# Regex to remove content between brackets and preceding method name

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have:

```
xVal.AttachValidator("CoverSheet", {"Fields":[{"FieldName":"FromDateTime","FieldRules":[{"RuleName":"DataType","RuleParameters":{"Type":"Date"}}]},{"FieldName":"ToDateTime","FieldRules":[{"RuleName":"DataType","RuleParameters":{"Type":"Date"}},{"RuleName":"Custom","RuleParameters":{"Function":"ValidateDates","Parameters":"null"},"Message":""}]}]}, {})
```

and I need " "

So an easier example is:

```
function(param1)

function(params1, param2)

method(text)

function(ex1, ex2, ex3)

newmethod(text)
```

to become:

```
method(text)

newmethod(text)
```

I have these in htmlMarkup form that I need to write into a window.document but I need to remove certain methods first.

I don't care about the content between the brackets, but I must use "function" in the regex to identify which statement I want to remove. I've seen various variations of this but not quite what I need. Anybody?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed:

```
.replace(/ *xVal\.AttachValidator\([^)]*\) */g, ""));
```